# error correcting that can used with CBC block cipher encryption algorithm

Tags: macos, block, encryption

I am using AES block cipher in CBC mode  to encrypt  by data. I am confused of using the appropriate error correcting code that can used with CBC block cipher for data retrievability? Can anyone help me?

Comment: You cannot encrypt data with CBC MAC as MAC is a message authentication code similar to a hash (SHA-1 for example) although it is used with a key for integrity and authenticity. It is a one way function, which means you cannot get data back from it, even if you have the key (you could try each combination if you do have the key though).

Comment: @owlstead: that, and really none of it makes sense, which is why I voted to close.

Comment: I am sorry , I din post it crct way, I am using AES block cipher with CBC mode to encrypt the data?

Comment: Verification is usually done outside of the actual decryption, because the algorithm doesn't know if the data is correctly decrypted, you can tack a hash of the original file after the file, before or after padding

Answer (score 0):

You should use AES CMAC (different from AES MAC) to provide integrity protection and authentication of the message. To do this, you should use a *different key*. The AES-CMAC should be calculated over the encrypted message.

Comment: Hello? Did this answer your question? Or is your question in need of another answer?